# Default to "Browse" tab when selecting images from Media Library?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

When browsing for an image from an Image field in Sitecore 7, is it possible to default to the "Browse" tab as opposed to the new "Search" tab?

The new search functionality is great for advanced users, however, my content authors are finding it confusing, especially with multiple languages showing up in the results. Selecting a search result item also yields an error in some cases, so I'd just like to disable it at this point.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

on this file \sitecore\shell\Applications\Media\MediaBrowser\MediaBrowser.xml 
you need to change order of the tabs  :
You will have :

```
 <Tabstrip ID="Tabs" Width="100%" Height="471px">
      <Tab ID="MediaLibraryTab" Header="Browse" Height="100%">
        <GridPanel Width="100%" Height="100%" Style="table-layout:fixed" Columns="3" GridPanel.Height="100%">
          <Scrollbox Height="100%" Class="scScrollbox scFixSize scFixSize8" Background="white" Padding="0px" GridPanel.Height="100%" GridPanel.Width="200" GridPanel.VAlign="top" Style="overflow:auto">
            <TreeviewEx ID="Treeview" DataContext="MediaDataContext" Click="SelectTreeNode" DblClick="TreeViewDblClick" ShowRoot="true" ContextMenu='Treeview.GetContextMenu("contextmenu")' Width="100%" />
          </Scrollbox>
          <VSplitter ID="MediaBrowserLeft" Target="left" GridPanel.Width="4" />
          <Scrollbox ID="Listview" Width="100%" Height="100%" Class="scScrollbox scFixSize scFixSize8" Background="white" Padding="0px" GridPanel.Height="100%" GridPanel.Width="100%" GridPanel.VAlign="top" />
      </GridPanel>
      </Tab>
     <Tab ID="MediaTab" Header="Search" Height="100%">
        <Frame SourceUri="/sitecore/shell/Applications/Buckets/MediaBrowser.aspx" Width="100%" Height="100%"></Frame>
      </Tab>
    </Tabstrip>
```

instead of :

```
<Tabstrip ID="Tabs" Width="100%" Height="471px">
   <Tab ID="MediaTab" Header="Search" Height="100%">
        <Frame SourceUri="/sitecore/shell/Applications/Buckets/MediaBrowser.aspx" Width="100%" Height="100%"></Frame>
      </Tab>
      <Tab ID="MediaLibraryTab" Header="Browse" Height="100%">
        <GridPanel Width="100%" Height="100%" Style="table-layout:fixed" Columns="3" GridPanel.Height="100%">
         <Scrollbox Height="100%" Class="scScrollbox scFixSize scFixSize8" Background="white" Padding="0px" GridPanel.Height="100%" GridPanel.Width="200" GridPanel.VAlign="top" Style="overflow:auto">
         <TreeviewEx ID="Treeview" DataContext="MediaDataContext" Click="SelectTreeNode" DblClick="TreeViewDblClick" ShowRoot="true" ContextMenu='Treeview.GetContextMenu("contextmenu")' Width="100%" />
          </Scrollbox>
          <VSplitter ID="MediaBrowserLeft" Target="left" GridPanel.Width="4" />
          <Scrollbox ID="Listview" Width="100%" Height="100%" Class="scScrollbox scFixSize scFixSize8" Background="white" Padding="0px" GridPanel.Height="100%" GridPanel.Width="100%" GridPanel.VAlign="top" />
        </GridPanel>
      </Tab>
   </Tabstrip>
```

You just change the order of tag TAB .

Comment: I dropped the modified file into the **\sitecore\shell\Override** folder and everything worked great!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Media Browser in the new Speak UI (available in Sitecore 7.?) you can accomplish the same thing by doing the following:

In the /App_Config/Include/Sitecore.Speak.config file replace the line:

```
<override xmlControl="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Media.MediaBrowser" with="/sitecore/client/applications/Dialogs/SelectMediaDialog" />
```

with the line:

```
<override xmlControl="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Media.MediaBrowser" with="/sitecore/client/applications/Dialogs/SelectMediaViaTreeDialog" />
```

Thanks Sitecore Support for the instructions.